# C++ TCP Proxy ASIO missing packets

Tags: c++, tcp, asio

I am building a small application for my company. I will spare you on the details why, but I was requested to build a TCP Proxy for a specific application and protocol that we have.

For this Proxy, it would make a TCP connection to a server that would send us data periodically, and the Proxy would mirror the data received to two other applications on different ports. For this, I used C++ and ASIO library. I will spare you the full code, but here is (what I think) the important part regarding TCP Connections:

The class belowhandles the incoming data received by our Proxy. Data received here should be sent to our clients.

```
#include "TCPInConnection.h"

namespace Proxy
{
    TCPInConnection::TCPInConnection(asio::io_context& io_context, std::string host, int port) :
        host(host),
        port(port),
        io_context(&io_context),
        socket(io_context)
    {
    }

    TCPInConnection::~TCPInConnection()
    {
        Close();
    }

    //Starts connection to the server
    void TCPInConnection::Start()
    {
        if(!socket.is_open())
            connect();
    }

    void TCPInConnection::Close()
    {
        if (socket.is_open())
            socket.close();
    }

    //Receives a callback. The callback passed should be called everytime a new packet was received
    void TCPInConnection::OnReceive(std::function<std::vector<uint8_t>(std::vector<uint8_t>&)> callback)
    {
        this->callback = callback;
    }

    //Handles the connection. If an error occured while connecting, try connection again. When connecting, call receive handler to read data received
    void TCPInConnection::connect()
    {
        socket.async_connect(asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(asio::ip::address::from_string(host), port), [this](const asio::error_code& error) {
            if (error)
            {
                this->connect();
                return;
            }
            asio::socket_base::receive_buffer_size option(8192 * 40);
            socket.set_option(option);

            receive();
        });
    }
    //Handles the reception of data. For evey incoming packet, it should call itself to receive the next packet. If socket is closed, try to reconnect.
    void TCPInConnection::receive() 
    {
        std::array<char, 4000>* receiveBuffer = new std::array<char, 4000>();
        socket.async_receive(asio::buffer(*receiveBuffer), 0, [this, receiveBuffer](const asio::error_code& error, std::size_t len) {
            if (error == asio::error::eof || error == asio::error::connection_reset)
            {
                if (this->socket.is_open())
                    this->socket.close();
                connect();

                delete receiveBuffer;
                return;
            }

            receive();

            if (len == 0)
            {           
                delete receiveBuffer;
                return;
            }

            std::vector<uint8_t> packet(receiveBuffer->begin(), receiveBuffer->begin() + len);
            auto data = callback(packet);
            delete receiveBuffer;

            if (data.size() == 0)
                return;

            std::vector<uint8_t>* output = new std::vector<uint8_t>(data.begin(), data.end());
            socket.async_write_some(asio::buffer(*output), [output](const asio::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
                delete output;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

The next class handles the output to our clients:

```
#include "TCPOutConnection.h"

namespace Proxy
{
    TCPOutConnection::TCPOutConnection(asio::io_context& io_context, int port) :
        io_context(&io_context),
        acceptor(io_context, asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port)),
        clientsMutex(),
        clients()
    {

    }

    TCPOutConnection::~TCPOutConnection()
    {
        Close();
    }

    //Starts listening for clients 
    void TCPOutConnection::Start()
    {
        connect();
    }

    void TCPOutConnection::Close()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(closingMutex);
        if (acceptor.is_open())
            acceptor.close();

        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(clientsMutex);
            for (auto c = clients.begin(); c != clients.end(); ++c)
            {
                asio::ip::tcp::socket* socket = *c;
                socket->close();
                delete socket;
            }
            clients.clear();
        }
    }
    //Sends data to each of the clients.
    void TCPOutConnection::Send(std::vector<uint8_t> data)
    {
        if (data.size() == 0)
            return;

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(clientsMutex);
        for (auto& socket : clients)
        {
            std::vector<uint8_t>* dataToSend = new std::vector<uint8_t>(data.begin(), data.end());
            socket->async_send(asio::buffer(*dataToSend), [socket, this, dataToSend](const asio::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
                delete dataToSend;
                if (!error)
                    return;

                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(clientsMutex);
                clients.remove(socket);
            });
        }
    }~

    //Still not used. Would be implemented later.
    void TCPOutConnection::OnDataReceived(std::function<void(std::vector<uint8_t>)> callback)
    {

    }

    //Handles connection of new clients. Everytime a client comes, it should listen for another one
    void TCPOutConnection::connect()
    {
        asio::ip::tcp::socket* socket = new asio::ip::tcp::socket(*io_context);
        acceptor.async_accept(*socket, [socket, this](const asio::error_code& error) {
            connect();
            if (error)
            {
                delete socket;
                return;
            }

            asio::ip::tcp::no_delay option1;
            socket->set_option(option1);

            asio::socket_base::receive_buffer_size option2(8192 * 40);
            socket->set_option(option2);

            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(clientsMutex);
            clients.push_back(socket);
        });
    }
}
```

Although the above works fine, I am losing some packets when our server is sending too much packets to the proxy (~15 packets per millisecond).

Is there anything I could do to avoid losing packets?

Comment: Why are you using `async_write_some` ? **some**, it may not send the whole buffer.. You could use `async_write` as free function, not member function of socket i.e. - `async_write_some`.

Comment: @rafix07 I am new to ASIO, so I guess I grabbed the first one I got. Which one would you suggest?

Comment: `async_send` also should be replaced by `async_write` invocation.